# Android Studio: Error after deleting file

Tags: android-studio

I got this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. > java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Guest Account\Documents\COLLEGE\FYP\7. Iteration 4\fridge iteration 4\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com'.

and saw 'could not delete path' so I decided to follow the path and delete the path. When I reran the app I got seven new errors:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt
>
> Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> Error:failed linking file resources.
>
> Error:attribute 'com.virtual.fridge:layout_behavior' not found.
>
> Error:error: attribute 'com.virtual.fridge:layout_behavior' not found.

In my even log I have two new messages:
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

21:10   * daemon started successfully

I am going to presume this is down to deleting that file.. is there anything I can do? Really new to android studio so I appreciate any help. Please tell me what other information I shoudl provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned the project and built it and it worked